# Extracting Form data from Checkboxes in Python

Tags: python, html, forms

I was wondering on how to extract HTML form data in Python from checkboxes with the same name. For instance,

```
<label><b>Optional Additions:</b></label> <br>

<input type="checkbox" name="optional" value="cardmessage" ><label>Card Message            $1.00</label> <br> 
<textarea rows="10" cols ="30">Enter Message Here</textarea> <br>

<input type="checkbox" name="optional" value="giftwrap"><label>Gift Wrap $2.00</label>           <br>
<br>
```

My issue is what method works best to extract the form data  from the checkboxes and radio buttons in python. Would I use the **form["name"].value** format or **form.getlist("getlist")** option or something different. Every  time I try to extract the data, I get no results. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it may just be a matter of naming it like `name="optional[]"` ...radio buttons with the same name can only have one value however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good library for parsing HTML. Here is its url

http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html